# Remove warn message about hidden settings in sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Sitecore has a dozen of hidden settings, but I see WARN messages in log about wrong value in this fields, 
foe example

*11168 08:18:11 WARN  The "EventQueue.Enabled" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "True"*

or
*11168 08:18:14 WARN  The "Templates.MaxInheritanceDepth" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "16"*

is is possible to hide this kind of messages ?

I understand that I can add each of this settings to config file, but I am lazy is it any settings about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no setting for that unless you change logging level to `ERROR` or `FATAL`.

Looks like those settings are already in your config just with empty values. Maybe it's enough to remove line like that from your configs:

```xml
<setting name="EventQueue.Enabled" value=""/>
```

If it's not in default `sitecore.config` file, check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for the information which patch this value comes from. There should be `patch:source` attribute (assuming you're using Sitecore 8.x).

Comment: I look for all string, like MaxInheritanceDepth for example, but did't find it at files

Comment: Sometimes the settings are in fact not present, if not then you can add them in yourself with the correct default value. Just be careful when upgrading that the default setting is not changed to something else.

Comment: @jammykam thanks for update. Didn't know that. Always good to learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore is aware of these warnings but they do no harm (at least that's what they told me). You can ignore them. In future releases they will probably (start to) disappear. They are logged as a "bug" in the Support system, but I assume the priority of that bug ticket will be very low.